# When trying to import the hugging face package "datasets" I get an attribute error from PyArrow

Tags: python, dataset, pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

I have tried to start environments with several different python versions and installed pyarrow in different versions. Nothing worked where can it be coming from?

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import datasets

File ~/anaconda3/envs/hugging_face/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/**init**.py:34
28 if _version.parse(pyarrow.**version**).major < 1:
29     raise ImportWarning(
30         "To use `datasets`, the module `pyarrow>=1.0.0` is required, and the current version of `pyarrow` doesn't match this condition.\n"
31         "If you are running this in a Google Colab, you should probably just restart the runtime to use the right version of `pyarrow`."
32     )
---> 34 from .arrow_dataset import Dataset, concatenate_datasets
35 from .arrow_reader import ArrowReader, ReadInstruction
36 from .arrow_writer import ArrowWriter

File ~/anaconda3/envs/hugging_face/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:45
42 from datasets.tasks.text_classification import TextClassification
44 from . import config, utils
---> 45 from .arrow_reader import ArrowReader
46 from .arrow_writer import ArrowWriter, OptimizedTypedSequence
47 from .features import ClassLabel, Features, Value

File ~/anaconda3/envs/hugging_face/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/arrow_reader.py:33
30 from datasets.utils.file_utils import DownloadConfig
32 from .naming import _split_re, filename_for_dataset_split
...
---> 61 wrapper.**wrapped** = wrapped
62 # Return the wrapper so this can be used as a decorator via partial()
63 return wrapper

AttributeError: readonly attribute

I have tried environments with python 3.9.6, 3.10, 3.11.4, 3.11.8 but nothing is working. I have restarted several times and installed different versions of pyarrow.

Comment: Welcome! Are you using google colab? What is your pyarrow version?

Comment: Can you export your environment packages in a text file and put it here? PyArrow might be conflicting with some other package you have in your environment. It doesn't necessarily have to do anything with your Python version. ^3.9 is a pretty stable release of Python.

Comment: I solved it updating conda to the new version, that is what was giving me issues. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.